# Javascript: How to call a value in an array for usage in GetElementsByTagName by setAttribute?

Tags: javascript, arrays, getelementsbytagname, setattribute

I'm a javascript beginner trying to utilize .setAttribute, array and GetElementsByTagName in a single function.

I want to make it such that the font color of h1 changes depending on what value is being input. Each value (0-9) corresponds to a specific value in the array. Then, using multiple 'if' statements (or other alternative ways), I hope to use .setAttribute to change the property of the h1 tag.

I keep either getting "Cannot read property 'setAttribute' of undefined" or "undefined is not a function", no matter how I tweak my code. Sometimes I get no console errors at all, but my code does not work.

```js
function change() {
var y = document.getElementsByTagName('h1').innerHTML;
var color = ["Grey", "Blue", "Green", "Red", "Pink", "Yellow", "Orange", "Indigo", "Violet", "Black"];
var x = parseInt(document.getElementById('cn').value);


 for (var i = 0; i < color.length; i++) {
     var bgcolor = color[i];   
   if (x == 1) {
  y.setAttribute("style", "color: blue;");
  
                        }
        else if (bgcolor > 9){
   alert('Please enter a number from 0 to 9'); 
    
                         }
                                         }
          
}
```

```html
    <h1>Header</h1>
    <p>
     Input a number from 0 to 9:<br>
      <input type="text" id="cn"> <br>       
      <input type="button" value="Change" onclick="change();">
    </p>
    </div>
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: `getElementsByTagName` returns a list of nodes, not a single node. So you can't call `setAttribute` on it directly, but only on its elements.

Comment: (1) `document.getElementsByTagName('h1').innerHTML` >> `document.getElementsByTagName('h1')[0]` (why innerHTML??);  (2) `document.getElementById('colornumber')` >> `document.getElementById('cn')` (why colornumber??) (3) Once a style attribute has been set, you need to reset it.

Comment: @abhitalks my bad sorry, I forgot to change it >.<

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no use of innerHtml.As document.getElementsByTagName() is index based and it will return an array of all the h1 elements of the page [more info on this](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_document_getelementsbytagname.asp). As here is only one h1 element,so you should write

```
var y = document.getElementsByTagName('h1')[0];
```

Also it is better to initialize the array color[] outside the function call

```
    var y = document.getElementsByTagName('h1')[0];

    var color = ["Grey", "Blue", "Green", "Red", "Pink", "Yellow", "Orange", "Indigo", "Violet", "Black"];


    function change() {
            var x = parseInt(document.getElementById('cn').value);
            var clr='color:'+color[x];
            y.setAttribute('style',clr);


    };
```

Comment: I replaced y (ie didn't use var y at all) with document.getElementsByTagName('h1')[0] (was getting the undefined error) and it worked. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

setAttribute is the property of singleElement but document.getElementsByTagName('h1') will return you an array instead of single element. Either use document.getElementsById('h1ID') or document.getElementsByTagName('h1')[0] .

More information https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element.setAttribute

Comment: It does **not** return an array, actually.

Comment: getElementsByTagName() method returns a collection of all elements in the document with the specified tag name, as a NodeList object. I was trying to explain in simpler language

Answer (score 0):

var y = document.getElementsByTagName('h1')[i].innerHTML;
The document.getElementsByTagName returns an array not a single element. So you can explicitly give an index and try.